# Console Applications in C# produce strange effect on other applications

Tags: c#, console-application

Hello and thanks always for your help.
I am having a strange problem here and I would like to hear your advice, comment or ideas about this. My trouble is that I can not reproduce the problem in my development computer

**The situation**
I have built a *console application* (in C#). It works great. Now other people are using it. 
In the computer of one of the users, there is another application. By the sight of it, it is a windows application. I don't know the code of it, and I have been told in rather vague terms that *"it was built in C#"*. 
That application is basically some initialization in a window, close that window and then a login window appear with a button, two text boxes one which is for a password. 
The problem that has been reported to me (and attributed to my console application) is that when the console application is running and not minimized, and then the other application is started the login window that appears does not have the first textbox in focus. Meaning that if I start writing nothing happens and I have to explicitly select that textbox to write in it. 
When my console application is minimized or not running, the other application starts with the first textbox in focus (I can simply start writing- no need to select the textbox)

Now, my console application is rather complicated so I built a very simple console application

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleFocus
{
    class Program
    {
        private static volatile bool keepRunning = true;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //We manage to set the way to finish this program with CTRL+C
            Console.CancelKeyPress += delegate (object sender, ConsoleCancelEventArgs e)
            {
                e.Cancel = true; //execution continues after the delegate
                //we leave the whole program entirely

                keepRunning = false;
            };


            while(keepRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I am still here");
                Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Hit enter to finish...");
            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

and also a very simple windows application. 
I tried the effect of both in the other application.
As expected even the simplest of the console application causes the loss of focus on the other application. Meanwhile the windows application does not cause anything.

So it seems that somehow console applications that catch ctrl-c to finish interfere with this application. (I have built my own applications and this does not happen at all)

Any idea why this could be happening??

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quite interested in the resolution of this one; I want to speculate that the console **is** a static class so there is potential for multiple events to be attached (i.e. all of the console apps listening for CTRL-C will exit upon one of them triggering) to it but I'm fairly certain that the console won't be shared across multiple applications.

Comment: I am unable to reproduce this on Windows 10. Can you post a [mcve] of a winforms application that is having problems with focus when you run the console application?

Comment: And the .NET runtime is not shared on a data-level across processes so whatever the console application is doing shouldn't interfere with the WinForms application, at least not in terms of subscribing to static events.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen and others. You guys are great... *"My trouble is that I can not reproduce the problem in my development computer"* ... and ofcourse the comments start with asking for an MVCE :).

Comment: Is the same behavior observed in the *code not known* winforms application, when just opening the windows command prompt without running any special program in it?

Comment: Basically, if you can show the behavior to appear for absolutely basic console apps, then you should just bounce the error report back to the developer of the winforms application, since they should implement a stable focus gain instead of relying on some instable default behavior.

Comment: I'm not asking you to produce an [mcve] that necessarily reproduces it on my computer, I'm asking for an example program that reproduces it on the computer in question. I fully understand the concept of the problem but you should try to reproduce the problem, even if you have to manually copy an executable to a different computer and try it there, every time. If nobody, including you, can reproduce it, you're not going to fix it either.

Comment: And yes, if you cannot reproduce it with standard winforms or wpf logic (depending on what the problematic program is using), then most likely you should punt the problem to the other developer. The fact that your program was the catalyst for the bug does not mean that your program has a bug.